# Should calcium propionate be disolved in a liquid when making yeast bread?

Tags: bread, dough, food-preservation, yeast

There isn't much information online for home bakers regarding the use of calcium propionate. I've started an Etsy shop and selling various yeast breads and other sweets. I'm going to start testing to see which percentage of the preservative works best for my recipes and gives me the best result.

I need my products to last a minimum of a week. Would it work better being dissolved in a liquid? Would my yeast survive the preservative better if the calcium propionate was mixed dry into flour? Any tips or insight into the use of Calcium Propionate in yeast breads would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With a solubility of 49 grams per hundred ml cold water https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_propanoate I would not worry about dissolving Ca propionate in anything before adding to your dough. As with sugar, the liquid already in the dough should be plenty to get your propionate dissolved.